# Optimize retrieval of all rendered pixel's data in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation

I need to perform some statistics and *pixel-by-pixel* analysis of a UIView containing sub views, sublayers and mask in a small iOS-swift3 project.

For the moment i came up with the following:

```
private func computeStatistics() {

    // constants
    let width: Int = Int(self.bounds.size.width)
    let height: Int = Int(self.bounds.size.height)

    // color extractor
    let pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: 4)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)

    for x in 0..<width {
        for y in 0..<height {

            let context = CGContext(data: pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
            context!.translateBy(x: -CGFloat(x), y: -CGFloat(y))
            layer.render(in: context!)

            // analyse the pixel here
            // eg: let totalRed += pixel[0]
        }
    }
    pixel.deallocate(capacity: 4)
}
```

It's working, the **problem** is that on a fullscreen view even on an iphone4 this would mean 150.000 instantiations of the context and as many expensive renders, that beside being very **slow** must also have an issue with deallocation, **saturating my memory** (even in simulator).

I tried analysis only a fraction of the pixels

```
let definition: Int = width / 10
for x in 0..<width where x%definition == 0  {
    ...
}
```

But beside still taking up to 10 seconds on even on a simulated iphone7 is a very poor solution.
Is it possible to avoid re-rendering and translating the context everytime?

Comment: I've never used it, but I believe you can use a Core Image filter - `CIAreaHistogram` - to get what you want. First, convert your superview into a CIImage (that I've done). Then get a histogram of the entire image. From the Apple Doc: *Returns a 1D image (inputCount wide by one pixel high) that contains the component-wise histogram computed for the specified rectangular area.* Again, I *think* this will give you an array of the pixels with a count.

Comment: Here's the link for the Apple doc - it made my first comment too long: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAreaHistogram

Comment: @dfd interesting thanks, i'll give it a try!

Comment: Last comment, I promise. :-) I'll post the code to convert a UIView and it's subviews into a UIImage/CIImage if you need it. You probably want to post a second question and (maybe) comment here to me so I'll see it. Good luck!

Comment: Oh no prob, i can do that :) thank you, i can check if this approach work, in such a case you can write a short answer and then i complete it eventually and check it if it works ;-)